# how do i make this duplicate the tab and type into the input bar?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser, replit

I haven't started on the web typing part but I need help with the starting part.

Here is my code

```py
import webbot
import os
import time
import random
os.system('pip3 install pyautogui')
driver = webbot.Browser()
print("")
driver.go_to('https://kahoot.it/')
code = input("The game id: ")

input_elements = driver.find_elements(xpath='//input')
driver.type(driver.Key.TAB,into=input_elements[0].text)
driver.type(code)
driver.type(driver.Key.ENTER,into=input_elements[0].text)

time.sleep(1.5)

username = "test"
input_elements = driver.find_elements(xpath='//input')
driver.type(driver.Key.TAB,into=input_elements[0].text)
driver.type(username)
driver.type(driver.Key.ENTER,into=input_elements[0].text)

time.sleep(2)

driver.execute_script("window.open(' ');")
time.sleep(2)
driver.go_to('https://kahoot.it/')

# keeps the loop running
while True:
  time.sleep(1)
```

I use repl.it's pygame for this

Edit: nvm I fixed the new tab now I need to type and hit enter into the boxes

Comment: don't you get error message? Code `loop not newtab` is strage and I don't understand what you try to do - it shoud be `loop < newtab`. BTW: `input()` alwasys returns string (event if you write number) and you have to convert it using `int()`. Code `loop + add` is useless - it should be `loop += add` or `loop = loop + add`

Comment: @furas no i changed the code